# How to customise ALL console windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Every time I start using a new conmsole application, I have to set my font to Consolas (FTW!), colours, console and window size for that application (Save settings for all windows with this title, or whatever).

How can I set, especially my font to Consolas, for **every** console window I **ever** open?

ADDENDUM:  Windows Server 2008 R2 (and I assume Windows 7) automatically keeps options you set, without asking whether to say them or not.

Comment: Windows 7 does indeed save settings.

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried right clicking on the title bar and selecting Defaults?