# Modify default properties of ALL future console windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customise ALL console windows.](https://superuser.com/questions/99694/how-to-customise-all-console-windows)

Every time I run a new console program in Windows I have to spend a minute or two configuring the console window properties.

In particular, I have to change the font, font size, make it wider, and make the buffer as tall as it can be. I also sometimes go change the quick edit mode, if I can be bothered.

Windows offers me to save these for all future console windows with the same title (or does this automatically on Win7), but is there a way to save it for **all** new console windows, not just those with the same title?

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/99694/how-to-customise-all-console-windows

Comment: Indeed. Thanks! (couldn't find that one by google nor by the built-in search...)

Comment: Excellent question. Glad I found this.