# is it possible to change the color scheme for ALL command line programs on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal

If I change the color in properties, it only changes the color for the current program (for example cmd.exe). Same for other settings (font, buffer size, etc.) Is it possible to make a global default setting for all Windows terminal windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customise ALL console windows](https://superuser.com/questions/99694/how-to-customise-all-console-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that, if while you have a CMD window open, you can right click the window header and choose either Default or Properties. Adjusting font sizes, window colors and sizes under default will make them the same for all future CMD windows.